# How to use generic with Knex.raw?

Tags: typescript, knex.js

I am trying to type the following code. Instead of using type assertion, how can I type it with generic?

```js
const result = await knex.raw<string>('select NOW()');

console.log(result?.rows[0]) //Print the date
```

Right now typescript will infer `result` as `string`, but it should have a shape like this:

```js
Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 1,
  oid: null,
  rows: [ { now: 2022-05-10T19:28:43.624Z } ],
  fields: [
    Field {
      name: 'now',
      tableID: 0,
      columnID: 0,
      dataTypeID: 1184,
      dataTypeSize: 8,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    }
  ],
  _parsers: [ [Function: parseDate] ],
  _types: TypeOverrides {
    _types: {
      getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
      setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
      arrayParser: [Object],
      builtins: [Object]
    },
    text: {},
    binary: {}
  },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false
}
```

I tried to look for the type for `Result`, but seems like Knex does not provide one by default?

https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/master/types/result.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

When using `knex.raw()` the return type comes from the driver's response itself.

If your using Postgres for instance, you're most likely using `pg` as driver, in which case it has a generic interface `QueryResult` that can be use for typing your expected response.

Take a look at the following example:

```
import { knex } from 'knex'
import { QueryResult } from 'pg'

const db = knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432
  }
})

interface Student {
  id: number
  name: string
  last_name: string
}

const fetchStudents = async (): Promise<Student[]> => {
  const response = await db.raw<QueryResult<Student>>(
    'select id, name, last_name from students'
  )
  return response.rows // rows type is successfully inferred as Student[]
}
```

Same approach can be followed for other DB clients, look at the underlying driver and try to find their generic response type.

Answer (score -2):

Remove await and the variable will have the shape that you want:

```
const query: Knex.Raw<Result> = knex.raw('select NOW()');
```

but you have to type it manually as `Knex<Raw<Result>`, where the `Result` is the shape of the result that you will get once you await the query. This shape will not be a string. Based on your code (`result?.rows[0]`) the shape will be something like:

```
type Result = { rows: [string] };
```

I've tested this in sqlite and the shape that I get is different, but still not a string.